# Webstore details for Matrix subitem

Tags: netsuite

We've created Matrix items with matrix subitems. We want to add webstore details to the matrix subitem but as per checking, webstore fields can't be seen on the subitems.

Is it not possible to add webstore details for the matrix subitems? If possible, where can we input the webstore details such as store and detailed description?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add those details for matrix items. If you want to be able to include extra matrix item information you can add custom item fields. The most common case I've encountered for that is when you want to add multiple images per matrix child.